Black Hole Formation -- How Can an Event Horizon be Observed to Grow?
This is a question about black hole formation. To be clear, I’m not suggesting that black holes don’t form. It’s that I’m having trouble with the accepted explanation so there’s a flaw in my logic that, hopefully, someone can point out.
Imagine you are in flat space and you launch a probe toward a black hole. As your probe approaches the event horizon, you see it (eventually) moving slower and slower and the signals you receive from it begin to red shift. The probe approaches the event horizon asymptotically and you will never see the probe actually cross the event horizon.
By the same token, there is no experiment you can do from flat space that will give you any information about what is going on inside the event horizon. In other words, there is no measurement or observation you can make from flat space that will tell you that something is now “actually” inside the event horizon.
If both of those things are true, you can never observe the event horizon grow. All the matter that falls into the black hole will appear, from flat space, to be concentrated just outside the event horizon.
But if that is correct, how do black holes form in the first place? Event horizons (where escape velocity = c) initially form in the very center of a collapsing spherical body, regardless of the initial mass.  If you are watching the collapse that forms a black hole from flat space, don’t you see all the matter collapsing towards the center but never actually crossing the event horizon just as you never saw your probe cross the event horizon? If this is correct then the event horizon – if you are observing from flat space – is where the singularity should be, a single point at the very center of mass.
To go farther out on a weirder limb, while it would appear to take an infinite amount of time for our probe to fall through the event horizon, black holes don’t persist for an infinite amount of time. Eventually, they evaporate via Hawking radiation. So what do we observe? Since we can continuously observe our arbitrarily tough and robust probe and we never see it pass the event horizon, does it still exist once the black hole evaporates? If not, why not?
In short, there seems to be a contradiction between what an observer in flat space experiences and what an observer falling into a black hole experiences. If black holes persisted indefinitely, that wouldn't be a problem. But they don't. Anything falling into the black hole that doesn't cross the event horizon eventually ends up in flat space again. So when it's all over, the flat space observer says, "I saw you get stuck at the event horizon but you never crossed it. You experienced severe time dilation. But now you're back." What does the falling observer say? It can't be, "Actually, I didn't experience any time dilation at all. I fell through the event horizon and was crushed by the singularity almost instantly."
If our probe does continue to exist, from our perspective, it has gone from being in flat space to being arbitrarily near the event horizon to being in flat space again. From the probe’s perspective, it flew towards the black hole which turned out to be a wormhole which deposited it in the far future in a blaze of Hawking radiation.
So how does this work? Why doesn’t the fact that black holes have a non-infinite life span – and, therefore, nothing can ever be observed to cross the event horizon – solve a lot of black hole paradoxes?
Again, I’m not suggesting that black holes don’t actually form. I’m just trying to figure out where I’m going wrong.

Does this answer your question? How can anything ever fall into a black hole as seen from an outside observer?

The question text sounds like it was generated by AI. I wonder if you get any response to your comments.

@JanG I wonder how long it will take for AI to bring this site to a halt.

Sorry, not AI. This is a legitimate question even if it's a bad one! Dale's cite is excellent. Apparently there is no consensus on the first part of the question about event horizon formation and growth.

@Bounder There used to be a consensus that the Earth was flat, but Giordano Bruno disagreed. Then there was a consensus that space and time were absolute, but relativity proved it wrong. Now there is a consensus that you can fall through the black hole horizon, but the information paradox says otherwise. Every scientific breakthrough in the history of science has been made against the opinion of the consensus. “The  consensus” has been the most reactive force even when science wasn’t completely corrupt yet. So why do you care for the consensus instead of the answer that makes sense to you?

@Bounder Please accept my apologies. When one relies on words rather than mathematics, it is inevitable that flaws in logic will arise. The meaning of a word is dependent on the associations one makes. For example, if you are falling into a black hole, you will never notice something like an event horizon. That exists only for an outer observer.

@Bounder As another example, the use of the word "inside" (event horizon) implies a prior assumption about the existence of something you cannot observe.

@safesphere when there was a consensus that Earth was flat, sorry? By the time Bruno lived, people knew the radius of Earth with good precision for 2000 years already.

@Anixx "Consensus" is not a universal agreement, but a majority opinion based on the official narrative and enforced by the propaganda and financial interests - https://i.sstatic.net/Qs3trj4n.jpg ;)

@safesphere when official narrative was that Earth is flat? Any prooofs, books to support your claim?

@Anixx It was a position of the Church that ruled Europe in Middle Ages enforcing its views by things like the Spanish Inquisition that executed Bruno for heresy. Don’t you remember what they’ve taught you in school that religion is an opium for the people? :) In any case,  I’ve failed my history class, as I liked physics more, sorry.

@safesphere this is abosolute bullshit, sorry, the radius of Earth was more or less precisely measured about 1000 years before any kind of inquisition. And that Earth was found was known much before this. Every sailor knew this both from own experience (seeing how rocks and hips disappear at horizon) and from practice because of navigation by stars.

@Anixx Propaganda is always BS. You are correct that some people had the proper knowledge long ago. This however did not prevent the establishment to proclaim the flat Earth to the masses and burn alive those who publicly opposed religious dogmas. How is this different from today? Have you seen any truth on TV lately? (Sorry, I’m not sure, on which side of the border you currently are.)

@safesphere give me a proof that there was any flat Earth propaganda by any official body anywhere since Eratosphenes till 19th century. This is absolute nonsense because under flat Earth theory sea navigation would be impossible.

@Anixx Wiki says that most scholars knew the Earth was round “regardless of how the public at large may have conceptualized our planet”. And what is a better propaganda for the public at large than the Bible? See “The Biblical view” section here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myth_of_the_flat_Earth - I think your confusion is that you think of the scholars while I was talking about the masses. In any case, this is not a history forum, so please do your own research, and stick to any opinions you like, as I have no interest in this topic.

It's the total mass that counts and we can indirectly observe a black hole growing through changes in the behaviour of objects surrounding it, those affected by its gravity and rotation. Naturally, these are historical changes according to the duration of signal travel time, depending on distance from Earth.
Escape velocity is >c at the event horizon, otherwise light would escape it.
Bear in mind that when regarding black holes forming through star death, the supernovae don't blow the entire star outward which then self-gravitates forming an event horizon as soon as it's sufficiently dense. The material at the core will go into direct collapse.
Bear in mind too that Hawking Radiation is a possibility but has not yet been proven.
What appears contradictory could also actually be acceptable: human clocks become irrelevant when it comes to black hole time, except when they are carried into the black hole by a human.

“Escape velocity is >c at the event horizon, otherwise light would escape it.” - It is stated everywhere that the escape velocity at the horizon is the speed of light, but your logic proves this wrong indeed - it is not the escape velocity, if nothing with this velocity can actually escape. A velocity “>c” is a mathematical term with no physical meaning in the real spacetime. A more accurate statement is that there is no escape from or beyond the horizon for the very same reason as why there is no escape back to yesterday from midnight or beyond: yesterday no longer exists.
